# Weights for retrospective cohort data

Tags: epidemiology, biostatistics, poisson-regression

Suppose you randomly identify individuals with a certain disease (cases) at time $T$, then you identify a sample of individuals without disease at time $T$ (but at risk for disease) in a population of individuals undergoing routine screening for that disease. The controls are sampled in a known proportion from the population of interest. Suppose further you are able to retrospectively ascertain all screening information in both groups and you interested in inferring the population level screening rates and the relative risk for disease adjusting for screening rates. Lastly, there are some subject level effects which you believe may mediate screening behavior and disease risk.

A probability model for the screening process is:

$$t_{i,j} \sim \mbox{exponential}(\lambda_s; t_{i,j-1})$$

where an $\mbox{exponential}(\lambda, t)$ random variable is a location shifted exponential distribution with location parameter $t$. So the number of screens that a person utilizes in a fixed time period has a Poisson distribution.

Disease develops according to another approximately exponential process

$$D_i \sim \mbox{exponential} (\lambda_c)$$

and is clinically detectable with screening for a short interval, $\theta_{d}$.

$\lambda_s \gg \lambda_c$ obviously. Disease prevalence is very rare in the population.

Disease status $D_i(t)$ is 1 if the subject has either screen detected or symptomatic disease at time $t$, 0 otherwise.

The time varying subject level effects (age) we denote with $X_{i,t}$, so all $\lambda_c$, $\lambda_s$, and $\theta_d$ are conditionally dependent on $X_{i,t}$.

This is a type of analysis whose name is not familiar to me. I'm inclined to call it "cluster case control" since the individual observation is a single screening period. However, we did not sample screens based on case/control status, but individuals. Because of the variability in lead time and individual screening rates, cases screen above the population rate and controls screen below it. Thus it's tempting to use some kind of sampling weight to account for this and obtain an unbiased estimate of the population level screening rate. However, the subject frequency:

$$w_i = \left\{\begin{array}{ccc} 
1 & \mbox{if} & D_{i}(T) = 1 \\
1/p & \mbox{if} & D_{i}(T) = 0 \\
\end{array} \right.$$

does not produce valid weights because of the lead time bias and differential screening (controls are followed for a longer period of time and so accrue more screening instances *and* person years, while cases are followed for shorter times and still accrue more screening intervals than cases in shorter time periods, yet still not more overall).

Is this even an identifiable problem???